# How to obtain a subset of Azure app registrations

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm looking to create a powershell script that identifies (and sends an e-mail) for any app registration secrets that are going to expire.  I know how to obtain a list of ALL of our app registrations by running one of the below commands

```
Get-AzureADApplication -all $true
```

Or alternatively by finding one app registration

```
Get-AzureADApplication -filter "displayName -eq 'Our App Name'"
```

I'm interested in obtaining the object IDs of only a small subset of app registrations (like only 10) which I can then loop through to find the expiry dates.

I'm fine with the send e-mail piece, but does anyone know if this is possible to extract the subset of app registrations from azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want 10, you can use the `-Top` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0#parameters).

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Top 10
```

You can also use the `-Top` parameter with the `-Filter` parameter. I like to use the combination of `StartsWith` to filter:

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Top 10 -Filter "startswith(displayName,'ABC')"
```

Comment: Thanks!  You're second command was what I was after.  Alternatively I found Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "Add app name here*" } | FT    also works.